# Error While Passing java Script object

Tags: ajax

i need to send the selected check box  data through ajax. I am storing the data in a object varaible and passing that variable through ajax,but while passing the data it is showing error. **NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments**

```
\$(document).ready( function(){

    \$("#target").click(function() // #target is the button on which click event is called 
{

                    someObj.loadGranted = [];
                    someObj.loadDenied = [];


\$("input:checkbox").each(function() 
                        {
                        if (\$(this).is(":checked")) {

                            someObj.loadGranted.push(\$(this).attr("value"));
                            someObj.loadGranted.push(\$(this).hide());

                        } 

                        else 
                        {
                            someObj.loadDenied.push(\$(this).attr("id"));
                        }



});
                        var obj =someObj.loadGranted;
                        alert("Granted:" +obj);
                        alert("DENIED: " + someObj.loadDenied);
                        //var selData={};

                        //  var selData=someObj.loadGranted;
                            //alert("seldata is "+selData);




                        \$.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "macrocall.cgi",
                          data: { macro: "lcinsertdb", CGISESSID: "$CGISESSID",Dataselected:obj}


                        })


.done(function( msg ) {
                            alert( "Data Selected: " + msg );

 });
 });



                    });
```

I am not able to pass the var obj. it gives error please suggest what can be done.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with all the backslashes?

Comment: i am using perl for server side scripting so differentiate between perl variable and jquery, the back slash is requierd in jquery '\$'.

Comment: is the above asked thing is not possible